# ylab and xlab title not showing up in a panel plot 5 rows 2column

Tags: r

I have a panel plot shown below. The main problem is ylab and xlab titles are not showing up.
How can I set it or reduce the graphics to have all within the window?
[image: panel plot]

Below the command used to make the plot:

```
par(mar=rep(2,4))
par(mfrow=c(4,2))

 plot(me.ts,las=1,
  main=" ",     # Main title for t`enter code here`he plot  
 xlab="Time",                 # Label for the x-axis  
 ylab="rainfall (mm/day)",   # Label for the y-axis  
 font.lab=1,                  # Font to use for the axis labels: 1=plain 
 ylim=c(0, 4), # Range for the y-axis; "x
 xaxp=c(2071,2095,4), # X-axis min, max and
 bty="l", lwd=2)  
 me.time = time(me.ts)
 abline(reg=lm(me.ts ~ me.time),col="blue", lwd=2, asp=1)
  m=lm(me.ts ~ me.time)
```

Comment: Please consider making your example reproducible. But I think your problem lies in your setting of the margins. Margins go around the plot-region, and if they need to be wide enough to allow for your axis texts.

Comment: The dataset is 8 time series I read using ncdf and then plot as panel using the above setting and the plot command for each ts. I repeated the plot command 8 times as above to have the panel plotted. The main problem as you mentioned is margins problem. Now what is the best way to set this correctly?

Comment: Why did you change them in the first place? What's wrong with the defaults?

Comment: In the first time I used the default and was having an error message:

Comment: What was the error? And please consider making your example [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).......

Comment: Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large  I then set the par(mar=rep(2,4)) and it worked but the subtitles of ylab and xlab. The program don't issue an error message which look strange to me.

Comment: You could toy with the margins, or try to make the entire plotting area larger. You could try par(mar=c(5,4,1,1)).

Comment: It looks I am not qualified for chat! I tried your setting and the sub-titles are showing up but too far from the y and x axis. If a way ti get it closer will be fine.